# How to dynamcially give tab value in bootstrap MVC4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, razor

i am using MVC4 Razor.. I have to use tab and the tab Name and URL has to be given dynamically from database

```
NavID   Name    URL Permission
1   Home    /DesktopDefault/Home    0
2   Employee Info   /DesktopDefault/EmployeeInfo    0
3   Product Info    /DesktopDefault/ProductInfo 0
4   Discussions /DesktopDefault/Discussion  0
5   About The Portal    /DesktopDefault/AboutPortal 0
```

i have to use bootstrap

```
 <div class="bs-example">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

</ul>
</div>
```

i am new to MVC and bootstrap..  How to do

Comment: 1. On page load determine the url or action, 2. Look for the associate name from the datbase, 3. Display.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest thing you could do is use AJAX (maybe jquery) and have an action in a controller that you would call and have the values you need returned.

In broad terms you could do

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetNavFromDatabase',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'

    })
    .success(function (result) {
        //Do here what you need to have the navigation using Javascript
       // e.g. $('#home').html(result.home); etc
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    })
```

On the C# side you will would do something like

```
public ActionResult GetNavFromDatabase() {

   var navs = dbcontext.Nav.ToList();

   var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
   return oSerializer.Serialize(navs);


}
```

The code above is not function but will give you a guidance towards what you need to achieve